# Salesforce 2016 release on sandbox: problem with landing page and auth access

Tags: community, landing-page, pre-release

We've experienced very strange behaviour related to community in all our sandboxes after 2016 stuff has been deployed.
First think we've encountered this Monday morning, our landing page is not available, i.e. it just returns 'Site is on maintenance' page (on all 3 sandboxes, instances cs17, cs20). Everything worked fine on Friday, no code or configuration related changes through weekend from our side.

We were able to fix it simply by setting default page as landing in community setting, hitting save and then assigning our custom page back. Again same fix applied for all 3 sandboxes helped.

But know when guest user clicks on any link from Landing page, it asks him to log in. Even when it clicks on link which should lend him to another publicly available pages, like help, tutorial etc.
And again pages are enabled in guest user profile, everything worked fine on Friday, and know exactly same problem on all 3 sandboxes.

Can anyone shed some light on this ? Have you encountered with similar problems after 2016 stuff deployed ?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Response from Salesforce support:***

A bug in the Winter 16 release is causing the community to not display publicly available visualforce pages to the community site guest user.

**Issue details**: *OptionsSelfRegistrationEnabled* and *OptionsSendWelcomeEmail* fields on the Network object are not accessible to guest users.

**Temporary workaround**: avoid using these fields in guest user context until this is fixed.